# Paypal checkout integration - Debit And Credit Card Problem

Tags: paypal

I've implemented paypal checkout buttons to my website. If I try to do a payment with my paypal email account it works fine, but if I try to do a payment with the Debit or Credit Card option, after putting all of my credit card informations, a window pops up and it remains stuck loading forever

[image]

Opening the console I've noticed those red requests with a canceled status. What can be the issue?

Comment: Do you have an AdBlocker? Otherwise, contact PayPal, it's probably an internal issue at their end.

Comment: no, it doesn't even work on my phone.